# Scrapy Response Changes After Visiting Page in Web Browser

Tags: python, scrapy, rss

Below is a spider I wrote to crawl an RSS feed and extract the first link and image title, and save them to a text file:

```
import scrapy

class artSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "metart"

    start_urls = ['https://www.metmuseum.org/art/artwork-of-the-day?rss=1']

    def parse(self, response):
        title = response.xpath('//item/title/text()').extract_first().replace(" ", "_")
        description = response.xpath('//item/description/text()').extract_first()

        lnkstart = description.find("https://image")
        lnkcut1 = description.find("web-highlight")
        lnkcut2 = lnkcut1 + 13
        lnkend = description.find(".jpg") + 4

        link = description[lnkstart:lnkcut1] + "original" + description[lnkcut2:lnkend]

        ttlstart = description.find("who=") + 4
        ttlend = description.find("&rss=1")

        filename = "/path/to/save/folder/" + description[ttlstart:ttlend].replace("+", "_") + "-" + title + ".jpg"

        print(filename)
        print(link)

        filename_file = open('filename_metart.txt', 'w')
        filename_file.write(filename)
        filename_file.close
        link_file = open('link_metart.txt', 'w')
        link_file.write(link)
        link_file.close
```

It goes over the Met Museum "Artwork of the Day" RSS feed and finds the newest artwork. Then parses the title and the link to the original (the link in the RSS feed is for a thumbnail) and saves them to individual text files. The title is used to generate a filename when downloading the image.

I know the parse function is a mess and that the way I am saving the links and filenames is ugly. I am just starting out with Scrapy and just wanted to get the spider working because it is only a part of the broader project I am working on.

The project itself draws from artwork/image/photo of the day feeds and websites, downloads the images and sets them as a desktop background slideshow.

My issue is that when I set the spider off it comes back with a response of "NoneType". BUT if I go to the RSS feed in a browser (https://metmuseum.org/art/artwork-of-the-day?rss=1) AND THEN run the spider it works correctly.

**Process that fails**

1. Call `scrapy crawl metart`

   - Output shows that the variable `title` has the type `NoneType`
2. Repeating step 1 results in the same output

**Process that works**

1. Open https://metmuseum.org/art/artwork-of-the-day?rss=1 in a web browser
2. Call `scrapy crawl metart`

   - Successfully saves the link and filename to the relevant text files

**Some troubleshooting I have already done**

I have used a Scrapy shell to replicate exactly the process that the spider goes through and this worked fine. I went through each step that the spider goes through starting with:

```
fetch("https://metmuseum.org/art/artwork-of-the-day?rss=1")
```

Then typing in each line of the parse function. This works fine and results in the correct link and filename being saved WITHOUT having to open the URL in a web browser first.

Just for completeness below is my Scrapy project settings.py file:

```
BOT_NAME = 'wallpaper_scraper'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['wallpaper_scraper.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'wallpaper_scraper.spiders'

# Crawl responsibly by identifying yourself (and your website) on the user-agent
USER_AGENT = 'cchowgule for a wallpaper slideshow'

# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True
```

I am very confused as to how the act of opening the URL in a web browser could possibly affect the response of the spider.

Any help cleaning up my parse function would also be lovely.

Thanks

**Update**

At 0535 UTC I ran `scrapy crawl metart` and got the following response:

```
2018-06-23 11:02:54 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.5.0 started (bot: wallpaper_scraper)
2018-06-23 11:02:54 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.2.1.0, libxml2 2.9.8, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.4.0, w3lib 1.19.0, Twisted 17.9.0, Python 2.7.15 (default, May  1 2018, 05:55:50) - [GCC 7.3.0], pyOpenSSL 17.5.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.0h  27 Mar 2018), cryptography 2.2.2, Platform Linux-4.16.0-2-amd64-x86_64-with-debian-buster-sid
2018-06-23 11:02:54 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'wallpaper_scraper.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['wallpaper_scraper.spiders'], 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'USER_AGENT': 'cchowgule for a wallpaper slideshow', 'BOT_NAME': 'wallpaper_scraper'}
2018-06-23 11:02:54 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
2018-06-23 11:02:54 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2018-06-23 11:02:54 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2018-06-23 11:02:54 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2018-06-23 11:02:54 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2018-06-23 11:02:54 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2018-06-23 11:02:54 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2018-06-23 11:02:56 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.metmuseum.org/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2018-06-23 11:02:56 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.metmuseum.org/art/artwork-of-the-day?rss=1> (referer: None)
2018-06-23 11:02:56 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://www.metmuseum.org/art/artwork-of-the-day?rss=1> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cchowgule/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 653, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/cchowgule/WD/pyenvscrapy/wallpaper_scraper/wallpaper_scraper/spiders/metart.py", line 9, in parse
    title = response.xpath('//item/title/text()').extract_first().replace(" ", "_")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'
2018-06-23 11:02:57 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2018-06-23 11:02:57 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 646,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 1725,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 23, 5, 32, 57, 65104),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
 'log_count/ERROR': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'memusage/max': 52793344,
 'memusage/startup': 52793344,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'spider_exceptions/AttributeError': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 23, 5, 32, 54, 464466)}
2018-06-23 11:02:57 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

I ran `scrapy crawl metart` 5 times with the same result.

Then I opened a browser, went to https://metmuseum.org/art/artwork-of-the-day?rss=1 and ran `scrapy crawl metart` again. This time it worked correctly...... I just don't get it.

Comment: There's no way browser can affect your scrapy spider. It's most likely just a coincidence.

Comment: @Granitosaurus could you run my spider once? The RSS feed updates at midnight UTC.

Comment: Is it at all possible that the RSS feed doesn't update till it is viewed in a browser and since I am running the spider programmatically at 0030 UTC my spider is the first one on the page?

Comment: It is possible but unlikely. The only difference between a spider and browser is that browser executes javascript. For your scenario to work the rss feed page would have to have javascript code that checks whether someone connected and if so would update the feed. However I feel that it's highly unlikely for something like that to exist.

Comment: @Granitosaurus please take a look at the update I just posted to the question. I don't think the website has any javascript, its a a plain XML file. But I really think that something is going on.